# Select All contents of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, select

I'm having trouble selecting all contents of the div. Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/304/

It's selecting only the first line of texts, the other lines are ignored. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

By browser is google chrome

**SECOND EDIT:**

Too bad i'd be answering my own question. But here i've got it to work on Google Chrome:

I've replaced

```
selection.setBaseAndExtent(text, 0, text, 1);
```

with

```
selection.selectAllChildren(text);
```

and it worked like a charm! Please guys inform me if it works with other browsers as well.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/308/)**

Comment: it works good for me. Both lines are selected !

Comment: its selecting all the contents fine..!

Comment: please include all necessary code, to understand you question, in your question as well.

Comment: Works for me in FF 9.0.1 and IE9, but not in Chrome 16.

Comment: Its selecting all in IE 7 but not in Chrome, please help!

Comment: guys i've found the solution, i edited my question and included the answer, please let me know if it works in ur browsers as well!

Comment: @user1099531 Now works in FF 9, IE 9 and Chrome 16 for me (though it continuing to work in the other two isn't surprising). I also found an alternative solution: `selection.setBaseAndExtent(text, 0, text, text.innerText.length-1);` which worked for me. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/311/)

Comment: hello, its working good on Firefox.

Comment: It's working on Safari 6.1.3. Great finding! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that removing webkit specific calls to setBaseAndExtent fixes issue in latest Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/309/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use innerHTML (or was it outerHTML) to get the entire text.

Comment: Did you even check the fiddle..?